# Resize of Image in Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written the following function to resize the size of the image I'm trying to display in
the tkinter window. Getting error: in add_img ->     lbl_logo = Label(window,
image=img_logo_new) -> TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type Image)
Getting error in the following code

```
def add_img():
    img_logo = Image.open("imgs/quacks01.png")
    img_logo = img_logo.resize((200, 170), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    img_logo_new = PhotoImage(img_logo)
    lbl_logo = Label(window, image=img_logo_new)
    lbl_logo.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes", pady=5)
```

Comment: Try to open with ```ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_logo)```

Comment: Please show the full stacktrace.

Comment: Also you need to keep a reference to `img_logo_new`.